# How to switch to a new version of the Kali Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, debian, kali-linux, version

When I boot in to the Kali Linux (from Live USB mode with encrypted persistence) it automatically goes in the `4.12.0-kali1-amd64` (current `uname -r`). Even thought I made `apt-get update` and `apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,') linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]*-[^-]*-,,')`

After running the second command it downloads and installs the image and header file of the `4.12.0-kali2-amd64` kernel version. (I can see them installed in the "Synaptic Package Manager" too).

Any other possibilities to switch to the newly installed kernel, because as I already mentionted rebooting wont help at all.

Comment: `uname -r|sed 's,[^-]-[^-]-,,'` returns the name of the currently running kernel so your `apt-get install` command shouldn't be installing anything.

Comment: https://wiki.debian.org/wl#Broadcom_BCM4311.2C_BCM4312.2C_BCM4313.2C_BCM4321.2C_BCM4322.2C_BCM43224.2C_BCM43225.2C_BCM43227.2C_BCM43228.2C_BCM43142.2C_BCM4331.2C_BCM4352.2C_BCM4360_devices_.28wl.29

Comment: I am trying to do what is on the given like

Comment: I do not understand either why after the "apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r|sed 's,[^-]-[^-]-,,')" command it downloads the image of the 4.12.0-kali2-amd64

Comment: Is there any others linux distros installed on your hdd (multiboot)?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you don't install a specific version, you install/update a meta-package(*). It pulls the latest kernel image (and associated packages....), add them to the set of bootable images, possibly uninstalls old ones, and sets up grub. To update all your stuff:

```
sudo apt update  # gets the latests package lists from the repos
sudo apt upgrade # upgrades everything
```

If you want to handle things manually at your own peril, at least run `update-grub` after installing the new image (requires `sudo` of course):

```
sudo update-grub
```

(*) On Ubuntu and derivatives, it's either `linux-generic` or `linux-hwe-generic`. The first is stable, the second (hwe: HardWare Enablement) is updated more often to keep your kernel up to date with recent hardware.